@angular-devkit/build-angular version for angular 18
I'm using Angular 17 in nx workspace and when trying to update to the latest version (which is currently Angular 18) it shows me the following error:
Found: @angular-devkit/build-angular@17.1.3
node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
  dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"18.0.2" from the root project
  peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">= 15.0.0 < 18.0.0" from @nx/angular@18.0.3
  node_modules/@nx/angular
    @nx/angular@"19.1.2" from the root project
    @nx/angular@"18.0.3" from @nrwl/angular@18.0.3
    node_modules/@nrwl/angular
      @nrwl/angular@"18.0.3" from @nx/angular@18.0.3
  peer @angular-devkit/build-angular@">=13.0.0 <18.0.0" from jest-preset-angular@13.1.6
  node_modules/jest-preset-angular
    dev jest-preset-angular@"14.1.0" from the root project

What I did?

Update Angular CLI globally by npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npx nx migrate latest
npm install --> in the step I got the above error


The error occurs due to peer dependency conflicts from third party dependencies @nx/angular and jest-preset-angular, which don't support Angular 18 yet.

@JSONDerulo but seems that nx support angular 18: https://nx.dev/nx-api/angular/documents/angular-nx-version-matrix

As per the given version matrix, for Angular v18 you need to use NX >=19.1. But it seems like npm tries to install NX v18

@JSONDerulo that's why already ran this command npx nx migrate latest
